# Returned variable is null from ajax to controller

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I want to make update with ajax.There is a urun.js and codes the following:

Urun.js

```
var url = document.URL;
var id = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
if (Control2() == true) {
    var product2= {
        No: id,
        Name: $("#ProductName").val(),
        R_No: $("#ProducrR_No").val()
    };
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/Product/ProductUpdate/'+id,
        data: JSON.stringify(product2),
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        success: function (sonuc) {
            var $toast = toastr.success("Update Success", "This product updated successly.", { "timeout": "2000" });

            $toast.show();
        }
```

The data is sending Controller page but it is null. My function in controller page:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ProductUpdate(Product coming_Pr, int id)
{
    var model = DataModel.ModelOneObj.Stock();
    var f_Product= model.Product.FirstOrDefault(p=>p.No==id);
    f_Product.Name= coming_Pr.Name;
    f_Product.R_No= coming_Pr.R_No;
    // model.SaveChanges();
    return Json(coming_Pr,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

The result:

```
{"No":0,"Name":null,"R_No":null}
```

I 'm using mvc Version : 5.2.3 and visual studio 2013. Please can you help me.

Comment: may be you should send `data: {coming_Pr : product2 }` object ?

Comment: Show your model. Does it have public properties with getters/setters.

Comment: @StephenMuecke I add a screenshot  , please look at that: [link](http://screencast.com/t/knPvw0RCJ)

Comment: Did you try without `JSON.Stringify`?

Comment: I've tried , at this time Product coming_Pr is coming null.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand the need to add the **id** to route to the action. You have all the necessary information for the action in the JSON (product2).

ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/Product/ProductUpdate',
    data: JSON.stringify(product2),
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    success: function (sonuc) {
        var $toast = toastr.success("Update Success", "This product updated successly.", { "timeout": "2000" });

        $toast.show();
    }
});
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ProductUpdate(Product coming_Pr)
{
...
}
```

Comment: You can try creating the JSON object yourself like so:
...
data:   {"No": id,"Name": $("#ProductName").val(), "R_No": $("#ProducrR_No").val()}
...

Comment: I tried as that but the result is same. 
" public ActionResult ProductUpdate(Product coming_Pr, int id) " coming_Pr is still coming null . :(

Comment: You don't seem to have removed the  **id** from the action

Comment: I resolves my issue from [link](http://screencast.com/t/Aowl6wqzzVSw)here. Thank you everybody for help me.